# Chrome (uBlock extension) inserting googletagmanager during website visits

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-tag-manager

Why is Google Chrome trying to access its tag manager website when visiting a website that has only static HTML with no embedded link and a very strong "Content-Security-Policy" in its HTTP headers.

I noticed this modification of its static HTML as:

```
<script async="" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-TMLW42T"></script>
<script title="domIsLoadedS" id="domIsLoadedS">var dataLayer=dataLayer || [];
(function(w,d,s,l,i,h){if(h=='tagmanager.google.com'){return}w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TMLW42T',window.location.hostname);</script>
```

The suspected link is: www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?d=GTM-XXXXXX

Is this Google Chrome (furtively) inserting HTML snippets during our website visits?

If so, how does one turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!

Once I disabled uBlock extension (v 0.9.5.0) of Chrome browser, the problem went away.

FYI: There are two variants of uBlocks:  uBlock Origin and just 'uBlock".  the plugin that I used is just 'uBlock'.

Who knew that extension could have malicious effect (although, this time it wasn't).

UPDATE:  uBlock Origin does NOT use Google Tag Manager.  Using "uBlock Origin" fixes my problem.

Source: [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en-US) -

Comment: Not really useful without knowledge of _which of the [myriad clones](http://imgur.com/PzOZhUy)_ is implicated. The "main" (by number of users) uBlock Origin doesn't do that.

Comment: Yeah, there are only two variants of uBlock:

* uBlock <-- this version 0.9.5.0 used Google Tag Manager
* uBlock Origin

So, it was plain ol' uBlock v0.9.5.0 that caused it.  Updated above answer to reflect this.

Source: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock/epcnnfbjfcgphgdmggkamkmgojdagdnn?hl=en-US

Comment: Updated answer to reflect a better alternative to uBlock, which is uBlock Origin.  Thanks, @Xan